# regex to match only English alphabet letter text

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I was trying to write regular expression that **only matches text** consists of English alphabet text that are more than 3 letters in python. I tried:

```
 regex = r'[a-z][a-z][a-z]+'
```

but it can't filter out strings like

```
 how@@
```

Any ideas would be appreciated:)

Comment: maybe (?:\w{3,}[^a-zA-Z]*)+ ?

Comment: What else would you want to allow in your matched character set other than english characters?

Comment: @EranMoshe thx! btw any ideas why mine is not able to filter out strings like 'how@@'

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi it has to be text consists of pure English alphabet letters like 'ajhdjjbbx' 'common', nothing else is wanted.:)

Comment: @XYlaven: Do you want to match the input string with regex or find matching text as per your regex in a larger string?

Comment: @XYlaven because you say a-z (1 time) and a-z (1 time) then, a-z (at least 1 time). there's nothing else allowed.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshii want to match my input with regex!

Comment: @EranMoshe that's why i am confused why 'how@@' matches, it's not supposed to match isnt it :0

Comment: @XYlaven the question was a bit unclear until your comments.. suggest to add few more input samples and indicate which ones should match and which ones shouldn't..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your regex to match the whole text exactly, you need to use `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) to make sure it doesn't match anything else in your input.

For matching strings that only contain English characters and at least three, you will need to use this regex,

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3,}$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LcDOH9/1)